# RedGate SQL Search Equivalent for Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008, redgate

I have recently started using Oracle. In last few Years I had used SQL server and used a tool called "[RedGate SQL Search](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/)" and found
to be very useful while maintaining projects with huge database size.

I need an equivalent tool for Oracle , Anyone having any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try [PL SQL Developer](http://www.allroundautomations.com/) I have used it too much, I have used RedGate tools also too much, the tool I mentioned for Oracle Database has most of features of "Red Gate SQL Search" for Oracle and in some cases it has some different and better features.

Comment: SQL Developer has a similar feature, I have an animation of it working http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/06/animated-gif-of-new-sql-developer-db-object-search/